# MySQL connection not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
$con = mysqli_connect('<remote server ip address>','root','*******','CSV_DB',);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

I have a simple program to connect to a mysql server that I created using phpmyadmin, however I get the 'could not connect' message every time I try to connect.

I know that it could be a number of different issues but I'm really looking for advice on how to troubleshoot.

When I ssh as root to the server I can access the server using the terminal and everything is fine.  However this connection which uses the same username/password/db/etc and I can't seem to log in. Also, the mysqli_error never prints-not sure why.

Comment: Is your *remove server IP address correct*? Also look at the following link to help us help you. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: created users, user.host combos, firewall, modifications to my.conf, what have you tried

Comment: IP address is correct because I can still ssh to the server and access mysql.  I've tried editing my.conf and I don't think there's any sort of firewall blocking traffic but part of the problem is I'm not even sure where to start as I'm not getting any error message

Comment: You say you can ssh and run mysql, that is local access. Can you run the mysql without logging in using ssh? If not you u have remote access or user rights issues

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick quick checklist for enabling Remote Connections for MySQL but read (6) first. If I have missed anything, feel free to edit.

1) Your remote user is connecting through an account that was created with appropriate `user,host` entries (look at output from `select user,host from mysql.user order by 1,2`). If not, look into the [`CREATE USER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-user.html) and/or [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) commands. Examine the output from [`SHOW GRANTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html) for the user.

2) You have done [`flush privileges;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html) (Some say it is unnecessary, others say it is).

3a) Locate your mysql configuration file referenced in 3b) below by reviewing info in [This Document](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) (or for Windows, likely down the `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.NNN` path). It varies by distro for Linux.

3b) You have modified and saved `my.ini` (Windows) or `my.cnf` (Linux) and changed `bind-address` away from `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, in favor of `0.0.0.0`. And you have created **and** rem'd out the following line: `#skip-networking`. It will look similar to this:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
#skip-networking
```

4) Restart the mysql daemon. How one does this varies by distro.

5) Firewall issues. Make sure the port, default being `3306`, is open to the outside world (which may in fact just be your intranet). This includes any other layers of firewalls, such as AWS EC2 Security Groups, or similar, if any.

6) Understand that there is a security risk associated with this. Unless you have knowledge of exposing your mysql server to remote connections, do not perform this.

7) Please run frequent security assessments with `select` statement listed in 1. above including reviewing the `SHOW GRANTS` for those users. Do not over-grant users with wildcard unnecessarily. Rather, give users the minimal privileges for them to get their work done.

8) Frequently examine failed connection attempts via the General Log and the Error Log as briefly introduced below.

For inbound, you can look at the general query log.

```
select @@general_log; -- a 1 indicates it is turned on for capture
select @@general_log_file; -- the file that it logs to
```

So all the queries *can be* logged to the [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) if the setting is turned on. Examine the log for "connect", but especially for `Access denied for user` to see failed attempts. Do this regularly (not every few years). I do it at least twice a day. Note, you can obviously automate the reporting through an external program. The outside world is going to **pound** your server to get in like the image below. It is a reality; brace yourself for it.

[image]

Check out the manual page for [The Error Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html) too, noting warning levels, and verbosity settings based on your version.

I would recommend that one create a backup copy by date (named as such) and delete the log files after backup to start fresh after the backup. The log files can grow huge in size rapidly, especially the General Log. Don't forget whether or not you have the setting turned on or off for logging.

You can use the two logs to determine if your connection attempt made it past the firewall during the steps here.

Comment: I agree, just to notice, most host providers do block mysql remote access. ;) and vote up.

Comment: yeah, we never got too far out of the gates to support this question, @maytham, one that I like to debug. Need a little back and forth with the OP :>