# How can I access my database mysql server using my local ip address instead of using localhost

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

Accessing  my database mysql server using my local ip address

```
<?php
    $col1='customerID';
    $col2='state';
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn,'dsuclass_gopi595');
    $sql = "select $col1,$col2 from customers";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    echo "This is my local ip address 192.168.1.7";

?>
```

Comment: somewhere [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887874) around step 3 perhaps. The assumption being, you want to go the route of "Remote Connections"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL connection not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887820/mysql-connection-not-working)

Comment: could be just dupe-hammered to the above

Answer (score 0):

- Replace `localhost` with the IP address in the connect call
- [Configure the database server to listen on that network interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52152)
- [Ensure that the user is GRANTed access when connecting via the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user)