# How to enable MySQL external access

Tags: mysql, linux

Good day everyone.
I'm getting "Can't connect to MySQL server on..." error every time when I try to connect to database from external servers. But on localhost everything is fine.

There are not `bind-address` or `skip-networking` lines in `my.cnf` file.  (I tried to add 'bind-address' with server actual IP, it didn't help).

Command `netstat -an | grep 3306` returns this:
`tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:3306 0.0.0.0.:* LISTEN`, so I guess 3306 port is open.

I also gave the user 'myuser'@'%' all privileges, then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` and restarted MySQL server, but it didn't help either.

Maybe someone faced similar problem? I'll be glad to hear any ideas.

PS. It's not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887820/mysql-connection-not-working) question, because none of the answers there helped me, as I explained above. It's not the closed port, nor a my.cnf configuration, nor a privileges.

Comment: Does `Can't connect` have a reason? Like `host refused connection`, or `no root to host` or so?

Comment: @Xenos, is there any way to see the reason? `Can't connect...` is all that I see.